# Privacy between 2 bitcoin accounts on the same ledger device

Tags: privacy

First of all please note i do not want to do something nasty or illegal. My goal is to understand.

I have buy a ledger device. It looks like an USB key and it stores my bitcoin accounts.

Here is what i've done:

- The devices first generates a random word list.
- I create a first bitcoin wallet account (let's call it W1)
- I create a second bitcoin wallet account on the same ledger device (let's call it W2).
- I suppose a public/private key is calculated from word list for each wallet account.
- I have buy some bitcoins on an exchange platform which asks my id-card. I have transfert this bitcoins to W1.
- I have buy some bitcoins on an ATM device with dollar bills. I have transfert this bitcoins to W2.

I am considering the bitcoins on W1 are not anonymous: If i do something nasty with this bitcoins, the government can technically ask my id to the exchange platform and follow transactions on the blockchain.

Bitcoins on W2 are anonymous because nobody asks my id card to get this bitcoins.

My question is: Is there a way to link W2 wallet to W1 wallet.
Is the government (or somebody else) technically able to match W2 to W1 wallet (and then to my real id) ?

Please note I have generate only ONE random word list. So i suppose there is a "link" between W1 and W2.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no link between any new generated bitcoin wallets. Nobody knows you created these two wallets from same wallet provider if you generate them from trusted wallet providers.
 Eventually, nobody knows you are the same person because you generated another verified account with ledger. 
But consider that all of the transactions of each bitcoin account is traceable.
If you need more privacy, get Monero coin which is one of the most popular privacy coin in the cryptocurrency world.

Comment: With an ATM everybody is anonymous ? Transactions are traceable but we cannot see my identity ? Thanks

Comment: It depend on identification process of ATM's . Some of them even take picture from you silently. I mean there are many ATM for bitcoin with different identification process. Yes your identity is not attached to your wallet or transactions of it on the bitcoin network but be careful about service providers or exchanges. They may keep record of your information such as IP address in their databases.